# multi-process C++ fifo

Tags: c++, ipc, pipe, fifo

In C you can create multi process application using `fork()` and you can then communicate using a FIFO pipe. I have learned that C++ only supports multi threaded applications and if you want a multi-process application you have to rely on `fork()`.

But in C++ type checking is crucial so I can't just pipe objects through a pipe without any risks. You could cast to `void*` and ask `sizeof` and the send everything through a pipe to typecast it back to the original object.

So why does this feel so wrong? Is multi-process architecture not used in C++ or are there libraries or better ways of doing things. I have googled a little and the only thing you find is multithreaded C++ or multi-process C.

The reason for wanting more processes is that I want my application to be as robust as possible. If my web service crashes I want my main process to restart it. There is no way of doing this multithreaded since you never know if 1 thread hasn't corrupted memory in another thread so if you get an error in one thread you have to restart out of safety.

Comment: What you mean is "multi-process".  *Multiprocessing* is a much broader term, inclusive of multi-threaded, multi-process, and SIMD (single threaded but simultaneously processing multiple data).  Retagged with `ipc`, which implies multi-process.

Comment: This question is too broad. You mention `fork`, then `void*` and `sizeof`, multithreading.. robustness.

Comment: It would certainly help to understand what your "objects" are that you want to process. How big are they, what kind of data do they contain?

Comment: All this stuff makes no sense whatsoever. A program that does not directly control hardware and does not interact with other programs is utterly useless. A program that does interact is a part of a multiprocess conglomerate of programs. Are you saying all C++ programs are elevator controllers?

Answer (score 0):

I assume by multiprocess programs you mean concurrently running two separate instances of a program with some shared data between them. Communicating between processes can be tricky. I have always gotten by with the pipe-typecasting method you described, or by using a local socket system to send data back and forth, however there do exist libraries for higher-level communication between processes, see [boost.interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) I would give that a look, and see if it can fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question right your main problem is passing data from one process to another via some kind of serial connection.

If this is the case and you are just passing flat data structures up and down the line there should be no problem using the method you already described. Just shot the whole bunch of bits down the line and cast to the corresponding type on the other end of the line. As far as you're only communicating with processes running on the same machine with executables generated by the same compiler and with same compiler switches there won't be any problem with byte-order, member alignment or whatever.

If on the other hand your data is more complex containing some kind of references to other objects lists of dynamic length or the like then you'll soon get into big trouble using the simple cast to void* and pump the data bit by bit strategy. So you'll definately need a more sophisticated approach at "serialization" and "deserialization" of your objects.

These (**"serialization"** and **"deserialization"**) are the two terms you might want to investigate further on to find the approach that best fits your problem.

As you'll soon find out these are problems to which "solutions" are invented over and over again with such a zoo of standards like XDR used by sun RPC and ASN.1 to name just a few that it is hard to tell which one will best fit to your use case.

If you're going with C++ you might want to take a look at the solution the boost has to offer (see: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)

Yet again - if it's just flat data structures you're passing back and forth don't bother with any overhead of that kind and just shoot the data down the line bit by bit.